# DateDiff() function help - Dates in 2 different columns

Tags: datediff, date-difference, tableau-api

I am trying to write a function to enable Tableau to calculate the difference between 2 dates, however they are in 2 different columns and I am having a bit of trouble.

Example:

**Column 1**

First Opened Date -  10/01/2014

**Column 2**

Reviewed Date - 15/01/2014

Obviously from this example there is 5 days between the two different columns.

These columns are aligned in rows due to a unique ID.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Thanks
Ellie

Answer (score 4):

I am not sure exactly what your data looks like, but you could calculate the difference in days between two dates by using the datediff function.

I am using this calculation: `DATEDIFF('day',[Order Date],[Ship Date])`

You can easily recreate this with the sample data set (superstore) that ships with tableau.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Please use `attr(DATEDIFF('day',[Order Date],[Ship Date]))`

you will get the correct answer